# How to assign a string to char variable?

Tags: c++, string, variables, char

I want to know how I can assign a string like "Hello World!" to a char variable.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char *input = "none";
  std::cout << "Welcome to Example\n";
  std::cout << "Type: ";
  std::cin >> input;
  std::cout << input;
  return 0;
}
```

How is this not working?

It is not showing an error but it is not printing the input.

Comment: Maybe...just don't. Use `std::string` and save yourself many ugly problems that are inherent to the use of raw pointers.

Comment: Input has no memory allocated. Try `char* input = new char[256]` and if you want to have more than one word input you must perform `std::cin.getline(string, size);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have allocated memory for the char array like:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    char input[BUFFER_SIZE];
    std::cout << "Welcome to Example\n";
    std::cout << "Type: ";
    std::cin >> std::setw(BUFFER_SIZE) >> input;
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
}
```

or you can dynamically allocate memory like:

```cpp
char *input = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

and delete at the end:

```cpp
delete[] input;
```

But if you are using C++, it would be simpler to use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << input << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```